# how should my hreflang look like on my root/index and nl/index if they are the same?

Tags: html, redirect, href, multilingual, subdirectory

I have a Belgium dutch written homepage, but because i'm upgrading my website to be multilangual, I have a copy of that dutch written homepage in the /nl folder.
like this:

```
root/index.html (homepage written in dutch (has a good SE ranking))
root/nl-be/index.html (copy of my root/index.html)
root/fr-be/index.html (a fully tranlated homepage)
```

I'm not a fan of my root-homepage to be a languagepicking-page, because most visitors are dutch. Is this the right way to leave it like this? if yes, how should my hreflang look like on my root/index, nl/index and fr/index?
I think I should 302 redirect by browserlanguage to /nl & /fr?...
Please help, I'm trying to find answers for days...